# Error opening Hive split hdfs Can not read SQL type double from ORC stream .commission of type STRING

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto, orc

```
select commission from dby_pro.ods_bi_user_event_ih limit 5;
```

Query 20201203_081000_00431_49yi4, FAILED, 1 node
Splits: 117 total, 0 done (0.00%)
0:01 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

Query 20201203_081000_00431_49yi4 failed: Error opening Hive split hdfs://mycluster/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/dby_pro.db/ods_bi_user_event_ih/day=20201130/ods_bi_user_event_ih__516fdf2e_af6b_476a_bf46_e1479d487f85 (offset=0, length=2849658): java.io.IOException: Malformed ORC file. Can not read SQL type double from ORC stream .commission of type STRING [hdfs://mycluster/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/dby_pro.db/ods_bi_user_event_ih/day=20201130/ods_bi_user_event_ih__516fdf2e_af6b_476a_bf46_e1479d487f85]

When I query by hive sql,no problem. but query by presto sql, have this problem.
Who can help me,very thank you!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59647638/2700344

Comment: Please report a new issue at https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/new. Be sure to provide repro steps, hive version, current hive behavior and Presto result.